# React Javascript Undefined Variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twilio

I am added a section to Twilio Flex QueuesView (which uses React/Javascript) but keep getting an undefined or empty variable for the variable val.

If I remove the "JSON.stringify(Promise.resolve("  from the function call getQueueInfoAxios() , I get the following error:

"Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

```
async addAverageAcceptTime(flex, manager) {

        //Sets color codes for above or below threshold
        const aboveThreshold = { fontWeight: 'bold', color: 'red' };
        const belowThreshold = { fontWeight: 'bold', color: 'green' };

        const TWILIO_WORKSPACE_SID = manager.workerClient.workspaceSid;

        flex.QueuesStats.QueuesDataTable.Content.add(
            < flex.ColumnDefinition
                key="average-accept-time-today"
                header="ASA"
                headerColSpanKey="average-accept-time"
                subHeader="Today"
                content={ (queue: flex.QueuesStats.activity_statistics) => {

                    const taskQueueKey = queue.key;

                    let val = "-";

                    
                    val = JSON.stringify(Promise.resolve(this.getQueueInfoAxios(manager, TWILIO_WORKSPACE_SID, queue.key)));

                    console.log(' Infunction result : val ', val);
  


                    return (<div style={belowThreshold}> {val}</div>);

                          }
                }

            />,
            { sortOrder: 3 }
        );

    }
```

```
     async getQueueInfoAxios(manager, workSpaceID, taskQueue) {


         console.log("Get QueuesView axios Function called")

        const TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID = manager.workerClient.accountSid;
        const TWILIO_WORKSPACE_TOKEN = manager.user.token;


        var currentASA;

         const url = 'https://taskrouter.twilio.com/v1/Workspaces/' + workSpaceID + '/TaskQueues/' + taskQueue + '/CumulativeStatistics';

         console.log('Axios call url', url)

      await axios.get(url, {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(`${testACC}:${testAuth}`).toString('base64'),
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
      }).then(function (response) {

          console.log('Axios call: response', response);

            currentASA = response.data.avg_task_acceptance_time;
            return (currentASA);

        })
            .catch(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                return response;
            });

         console.log('Axios call: currentASA', currentASA);
  
  
    }



  
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly if you want people to not just move on to a next question.

Comment: what's the intent of `JSON.stringify(Promise.resolve(...))` - why do you want to stringify a Promise object? Oh, did you think `Promise.resolve` gives you the fulfilled value of a promise?

Comment: I intially tried Promise.solve, but I kept receiving undefined, so I attempted JSON.stringify which was mentioned on another post but it returned an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You have a few problems here.

The first problem is not a bug in your code, per se. It appears that you are making an API request to the Twilio API from your front end code. While I understand that this is within Flex and one would assume that only employees would be using the system, it remains bad practice to embed your Account SID and Auth Token within client side code where it could be extracted by a malicious user and used to abuse your account. I recommend you follow this tutorial on [how to securely call a Twilio Function from Flex](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/plugins/call-functions) to get the data you want from TaskRouter into Flex.

---

I will explain what is going wrong in your code though too.

Firstly, `Promise.resolve()` returns a new promise object that is resolved with the value that you pass to it. You must still call `.then` to extract that value (or `await` the promise). So calling `JSON.stringify(Promise.resolve("anything"))` will result in you trying to stringify a promise object, which, according to a quick test I just did, results in the string `"{}"`.

Secondly, you're not returning anything from your `getQueueInfoAxios` function, which is causing the rest of your issues.

Your problem comes down to a confusion between `async/await` and `then/catch` in the function. Since you have defined the function as async and you are using await it would be best to commit to that and use `try/catch` around your call to the API and return your response from there. Like this:

```js
  try {
    const response = await axios
      .get(url, {
        headers: {
          Authorization:
            "Basic " + Buffer.from(`${testACC}:${testAuth}`).toString("base64"),
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      })
    console.log("Axios call: response", response);
    currentASA = response.data.avg_task_acceptance_time;
    console.log("Axios call: currentASA", currentASA);  
    return currentASA;
  } catch(error) {
    console.log(response);
    return response;
  }
```

You can then call this like:

```js
val = await this.getQueueInfoAxios2(manager, TWILIO_WORKSPACE_SID, queue.key);
```

This should sort out your code, but please stop embedding your credentials in the client side and [follow the tutorial to make this correct](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/plugins/call-functions).

Comment: Thank you, I changed the axios and then i change the Promise to the following : 
 val = this.getQueueInfoAxios2(manager, TWILIO_WORKSPACE_SID, queue.key).then(data => val = data);

But when I try to return val, it does not change from a promise and I get the "Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise])." Error

Comment: You can use `await` again. I've updated my answer to show this. But I must recommend again that you stop making the call directly to the Twilio API from this client-side code.

Comment: Finally, if this does help you out and answer your question, please mark the answer as correct so that other people can see that it helped too.

Comment: If i add an await here :
  await this.getQueueInfoAxios2(manager, TWILIO_WORKSPACE_SID, queue.key).then(function (value) {

I get the following error message:

 'await' is only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules (311:21).

I think that i can't add an async/await command within the flex.QueuesStats.QueuesDataTable.Content.add( section.

Comment: Ah, there’s a function in there. You’d need to add `async` to `content={ (queue: flex.QueueStats.activity_statistics)  => {`.

Comment: So i added it like this : 
 content={async (queue: flex.QueuesStats.WorkerQueue) => {

and then used the await but got the following error: 
 
"Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

Comment: Ah, hmm, this light need a rethink actually. I wasn’t considering that you were making asynchronous calls during rendering the components. That should be done outside of rendering as part of the component lifecycle and update the component state which you can then render.